# Google Cloud Platform cannot access on premise network from GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am trying to configure infrastructure between GCP and On-Premise via HA VPN.

1. Creating HA VPN by follow [this document](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/using-ha-vpn-with-fortigate).
2. Allow all traffic from GCP to On-Premise and On-Premise to GCP.
3. Testing connectivity from On-Premise to GCP (ping from PC to VMs and ping from firewall to VMs) is work.
4. Testing connectivity from GCP to On-Premise (ping from VMs to firewall and ping from VMs to Onprem PC) is fail.

How can I get GCP to connect to my on-premise network?

Comment: Given the information provided, I would be persuaded to think that your Fortigate firewall is not allowing ICMP packets. Can you verify on your Fortigate firewall that ICMP packets are allowed?

Comment: not enough data, but I'm wondering if you have created routes for On-Premise network, on GCP VM and/or VPC

Answer (score 1):

Try running connectivity test[1] from GCP to on-prem and see if the connectivity test shows successful. I suspect there is some issue with on-prem network not allowing packets. I would recommend running a tcpdump  on your on-prem Firewall while trying to connect from the GCP instance and see where the packet is dropping.

[1]https://cloud.google.com/network-intelligence-center/docs/connectivity-tests/how-to/running-connectivity-tests